# Why is "this" more effective than a saved selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was doing [this test case](http://jsperf.com/this-vs-thatjames) to see how much using the `this` selector speeds up a process. While doing it, I decided to try out pre-saved element variables as well, assuming they would be even faster. Using an element variable saved before the test appears to be the slowest, quite to my confusion. I though only having to "find" the element once would immensely speed up the process. Why is this not the case?

Here are my tests from fastest to slowest, in case anyone can't load it:

1

```
$("#bar").click(function(){
    $(this).width($(this).width()+100);
});
$("#bar").trigger( "click" );
```

---

2

```
$("#bar").click(function(){
    $("#bar").width($("#bar").width()+100);
});
$("#bar").trigger( "click" );
```

---

3

```
var bar = $("#bar");
bar.click(function(){
    bar.width(bar.width()+100);
});
bar.trigger( "click" );
```

---

4

```
par.click(function(){
    par.width(par.width()+100);
});
par.trigger( "click" );
```

I'd have assumed the order would go 4, 3, 1, 2 in order of which one has to use the selector to "find" the variable more often.

UPDATE: I have a [theory](http://jsperf.com/maybe-it-has-to-do-with-the-events), though I'd like someone to verify this if possible. I'm guessing that on click, it has to reference the variable, instead of just the element, which slows it down.

Comment: And even faster still (AND immune to the side-effects of testing): `(document.getElementById('bar').onclick = function() {this.style.width = this.offsetWidth+10+"px";})();`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Fixed test case: http://jsperf.com/this-vs-thatjames/10**

TL;DR: Number of click handlers executed in each test grows because the element is not reset between tests.

The biggest problem with testing for micro-optimizations is that you have to be very very careful with what you're testing. There are many cases where the testing code interferes with what you're testing. Here is an [example](http://mrale.ph/blog/2014/02/23/the-black-cat-of-microbenchmarks.html) from Vyacheslav Egorov of a test that "proves" multiplication is almost instantaneous in JavaScript because the testing loop is removed entirely by the JavaScript compiler:

```
// I am using Benchmark.js API as if I would run it in the d8.
Benchmark.prototype.setup = function() {
  function multiply(x,y) {
    return x*y;
  }
};

var suite = new Benchmark.Suite;
suite.add('multiply', function() {
  var a = Math.round(Math.random()*100),
      b = Math.round(Math.random()*100);

  for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
     multiply(a,b);
  }
})
```

Since you're already aware there is something counter-intuitive going on, you should pay extra care.

First of all, you're not testing selectors there. Your testing code is doing: zero or more selectors, depending on the test, a function creation (which in some cases is a closure, others it is not), assignment as the click handler and triggering of the jQuery event system.

Also, the element you're testing on is changing between tests. It's obvious that the width in one test is more than the width in the test before. That isn't the biggest problem though. The problem is that the element in one test has X click handlers associated. The element in the next test has X+1 click handlers.
So when you trigger the click handlers for the last test, you also trigger the click handlers associated in all the tests before, making it much slower than tests made earlier.

I fixed the jsPerf, but keep in mind that it still doesn't test just the selector performance. Still, the most important factor that skewes the results is eliminated.

---

Note: There are some [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/mathiasbynens/using-jsperf-correctly) and a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RLbAKxCAdI8) about doing good performance testing with jsPerf, focused on common pitfalls that you should avoid. Main ideas:

- don't define functions in the tests, do it in the setup/preparation phase
- keep the test code as simple as possible
- compare things that do the same thing or be upfront about it
- test what you intend to test, not the setup code
- isolate the tests, reset the state after/before each test
- no randomness. mock it if you need it
- be aware of browser optimizations (dead code removal, etc)

Comment: Oh, wow, I assumed that jsperf would reset all of that somehow. I was very ignorant of how it worked. I assumed it ran everything in separate modules or reset everything on its own inbetween tests.

Answer (score 6):

You don't really test the performance between the different techniques.

If you look at the output of the console for this modified test:
http://jsperf.com/this-vs-thatjames/8

You will see how many event listeners are attached to the `#bar` object.
And you will see that they are not removed at the beginning for each test.

So the following tests will always become slower as the previous ones because the trigger function has to call all the previous callbacks.

Comment: When I write benchmarks, I often write a loop that runs through all of the benchmarks at least twice, to account for odd effects that might make the first runs be more or less efficient than normal (e.g. page faults, disk caches, and so forth). It's nice to see an example where this practice would have caught a real bug in my benchmark!

Comment: @Hurkyl writing good test is a pain. You have to take so many things into account, that it is more likely that you do a mistake then creating a meaningful test. You not only need to perfectly know your code, but also the behavior of the apis that are involved. And you need to determine if the way the test is done, reflects the real world scenario. e.g. if a function performs only better if it is called at least x times a second, and in the real world scenario it can be call at most y times a second (where y < x ) then such stress tests would also be misleading.

Answer (score 3):

Some of this increase in slowness is because the object reference is already found in memory, so the compiler doesn't have to go looking in memory for the variable

```
$("#bar").click(function(){         
    $(this).width($(this).width()+100); // Only has to check the function call
});                                     // each time, not search the whole memory
```

as opposed to

```
var bar = $("#bar");
...
bar.click(function(){
    bar.width(bar.width()+100);         // Has to search the memory to find it 
});                                     // each time it is used
```

As zerkms said, dereferencing (having to look up the memory reference as I describe above) has [some but little effect](http://jsperf.com/function-call-vs-closure) on the performance

Thus the main source of slowness in difference for the tests you have performed is the fact that the DOM is not reset between each function call. In actuality, a saved selector performs just about as fast as `this`

Comment: you mean there is no dereferencing with this?

Comment: @mpm I believe so, but I could be wrong on that fact. Perhaps it only searches for the variable once, I'm unsure

Comment: I don't believe variable dereference is **that** expensive http://jsperf.com/function-call-vs-closure

Comment: As you can see - the variable lookup compared to a function call is instantaneous.

Comment: "is likely something else" --- it's the state. You cannot reset the state of the DOM and jQuery between test calls. It would be too complicated

Comment: I'm curious why this was downvoted - could the person please explain why this is not useful?

Comment: Not regarding any downvote, but the larger part of this explanation is not the correct answer. Read the answer by @t.niese which explains what the issue is. The code in the perf test does not test what it is supposed to test, but rather builds up loads of click handlers. You can easily test it by editing the original test and exchanging the code between the first and third test and see you'll find different results than the original test does.

Comment: @robert.westerlund Do I not reference that fact in the last part of my answer? Am I not trying to ask the actual question at hand - not the fact that the tests the OP performed were incorrect?

Comment: @ZachSaucier You're trying to explain a phenomenon that doesn't actually happen. De-referencing the variable is orders of magnitude faster than calling the jQuery function on what is essentially another variable. Keep in mind that looking up the variable par and the variable $ should have similar timing.

Comment: Yes, you reference it in the last part of the answer, but when I read it it felt more like a side note. I made the comment only to help future readers of this question find an answer which explains the actual problem. It was not my purpose to make you feel offended in any way, but rather to provide assistance for people reading the question trying to find an answer. If you do feel offended by my comment and feel like it should be removed, please let me know and I'll remove it.

Comment: By the way, if you remove the part of the answer which discusses the deferencing, or at least reorder the answer so that the important part comes first, I'll gladly remove my downvote and my comments, since neither of them would then be valid anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the performance results you're getting has nothing to do with the code. If you look at [these edited tests](http://jsperf.com/this-vs-thatjames/4), you can see that having the same code in two of the tests (first and last) yield totally different results.

Answer (score -4):

I don't know, but if I had to guess I would say it is due to concurrency and multithreading.

When you do `$(...)` you call the jQuery constructor and create a new object that gets stored in the memory. However, when you reference to an existing variable you do not create a new object (duh).

Although I have no source to quote I believe that every javascript event gets called in its own thread so events don't interfere with eachother. By this logic the compiler would have to get a lock on the variable in order to use it, which might take time.

Once again, I am not sure. Very interesting test btw!

Comment: All the JavaScript code (except for workers) is executed by the same thread, in something called the event loop. You take one event, execute every handler associated with it, then grab the next one.

Comment: @Tibos so per that logic, if one event handler or whatever piece of code takes a long amount of time, it locks up?